# MFC draw new at maximized window

Tags: c++, mfc, resize, maximize

I've an MFC MDI Application. If I resize my window, I'll get the window with the new scale.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CmyView, CFormView)
    ON_WM_SIZE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

    void CmyView::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy) 
{
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(&rc);

   if (::IsWindow(m_XYZ.GetSafeHwnd()))
   {
       m_XYZ.MoveWindow (rc.left, rc.top,rc.right,rc.bottom);
   }
}
```

Everything works fine, but if I click the maximize button, the screen won't resize itself. I'll get a white border at the right and at the bottom.
Is there any change to get the maximize event like the resize event (ON_WM_SIZE()) ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you look at handling [WM_SYSCOMMAND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360(v=vs.85).aspx) for SC_MAXIMIZE?

Comment: I can't believe this. WM_SIZE is also sent when the window is maximized. There must be another problem. Just set a breakpoint and maximize...

Comment: yes, it's weird. If I click the Cancle-button, the ONSize function is called....

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers! I found the problem.

As I said, I've an MDI application. I used the ON_SIZE event in my first and second View. The maximize or minimize event is only called in the MainFrame.

But the problem is still alive.

```
void CMainFrame::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy) 
{
   RECT rc;
   GetClientRect(&rc);

   CWnd* ViewWin = GetWindow(0); // this is my first view

   if (::IsWindow(ViewWin->GetSafeHwnd()))
   {
   if (nType == SIZE_MAXIMIZED)
        ViewWin->ShowWindow(SW_MAXIMIZE);
   else if (nType == SIZE_MINIMIZED)
        ViewWin->ShowWindow(SW_MINIMIZE);
   else
        ViewWin->MoveWindow (rc.left, rc.top,rc.right,rc.bottom);
   }

   CWnd* ViewWin1 = GetWindow(1);   // this is my second view 
   if (::IsWindow(ViewWin1->GetSafeHwnd()))
   {
   if (nType == SIZE_MAXIMIZED)
        ViewWin1->ShowWindow(SW_MAXIMIZE);
   else if (nType == SIZE_MINIMIZED)
        ViewWin1->ShowWindow(SW_MINIMIZE);
   else
       ViewWin1->MoveWindow (rc.left, rc.top,rc.right,rc.bottom);
   }
}
```

I'll get into the maximize or minimize case but nothing happend.